# After Xamarin.forms update having a problem with json data from Api

Tags: laravel, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Laravel 7.0 for my Xamarin Apps Backend. Up until i updated xamarin.forms it was working fine. Now i cant show the products under a category. this is how i get products

```
$products = Product::select("products.*",DB::raw("COALESCE(cart.quantity,0) as cart_quantity"),DB::raw("COALESCE(cart.id,0) as cart_id"),DB::raw("(0) as SecondLoad"),DB::raw("(0) as checkPickerLoad"),DB::raw("IF ((select count(favourite_products.product_id) from favourite_products where favourite_products.product_id = products.id and favourite_products.user_id='$user_id' and favourite_products.status='AC') > 0,'Favourites_selected.png','Favourites.png') as favourite"),DB::raw("(select product_variations.price from product_variations where product_variations.product_id = products.id and product_variations.status='AC' limit 1) as price"),DB::raw("(select product_variations.special_price from product_variations where product_variations.product_id = products.id and product_variations.status='AC' limit 1) as special_price"),DB::raw("(select round((product_variations.price - product_variations.special_price)*100 / product_variations.price) from product_variations where product_variations.product_id = products.id and product_variations.status='AC' limit 1) as discount"))->join('product_variations', 'product_variations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')->leftJoin("cart", function ($join) use ($user_id) {
            $join->on("cart.product_id", "=", "products.id");
            $join->where(["cart.user_id" => $user_id, "cart.status" => "AC"]);
        })->with(['get_product_variations' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['product_units' => function ($q) {
                $q->select('id', 'name', 'h_name');
            }])->where('status', 'AC');
        }, 'product_brand' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name as brand_name');
        }])
        ->where(['products.status' => 'AC', 'category_id' => $request->category_id, 'product_variations.status' => 'AC'])
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->orderBy('products.name')
        ->get();
```

this is the format i get.

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "OK",
"data": [{
            "id": 180,
            "name": "Blueberry Juice",
            "category_id": 6,
            "description": "Juice","image":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/uploads\/products\/5f150c6847a77_Wild-Blueberry-Juice.jpg","is_featured":0,"is_quick_grab":0,"is_offered":0,"status":"AC","brand_id":1,"h_name":null,"h_description":null,"price":"2.00","quantity":0,"cgst":"0.00","sgst":"0.00","igst":"0.00","created_at":"2020-08-15T11:35:27.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-08-15T11:35:27.000000Z","cart_quantity":0,"cart_id":0,"SecondLoad":0,"checkPickerLoad":0,"favourite":"Favourites.png","special_price":"1.00","discount":"50","get_product_variations":[{"id":7,"product_id":180,"unit_id":6,"weight":1,"price":"2.00","special_price":"1.00","status":"AC","created_at":"2020-07-20T03:16:01.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-20T03:16:01.000000Z","product_units":{"id":6,"name":"Each","h_name":""}}],"product_brand":{"id":1,"brand_name":"Local"}}]}
```

Unfortunately the page doesnt show any data right now... If i change the code to this

```
$products = Product::join('product_variations', 'product_variations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')->leftJoin("cart", function ($join) use ($user_id) {
            $join->on("cart.product_id", "=", "products.id");
            $join->where(["cart.user_id" => $user_id, "cart.status" => "AC"]);
        })->with(['get_product_variations' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['product_units' => function ($q) {
                $q->select('id', 'name', 'h_name');
            }])->where('status', 'AC');
        }, 'product_brand' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name as brand_name');
        }])
        ->where(['products.status' => 'AC', 'category_id' => $request->category_id, 'product_variations.status' => 'AC'])
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->orderBy('products.name')
        ->get();
```

which means deleting the select("***") then it works again, of course with lots of missing information. I have been working on it for last 4 days. I searched everywhere, all the xamarin groups etc.. Not a chance.. it all happened after xamarin.forms update to latest version. for some reason when i send the data with select it cant process it..

Im adding my product logic as well. Product, ProductDetail and SearchProduct Tasks are the ones with issue.

```
 public class ProductLogic
{
    public static async Task<ProductResponce> GetProducts(int CategoryId, string UserId)
    {
        ProductResponce productResponce;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var url = string.Format(Config.GetProductList, CategoryId, UserId);
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            productResponce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductResponce>(json);
        }

        return productResponce;
    }

    public static async Task<ProductDetailResponce> GetProduct(int ProductId)
    {
        ProductDetailResponce product = new ProductDetailResponce();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var url = string.Format(Config.GetSingleProduct, ProductId);
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var productDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDetailResponce>(json);
            product = productDetail;
        }

        return product;
    }

    public static async Task<SearchProductResponce> GetSearchProducts(string text, string UserId)
    {
        SearchProductResponce productResponce;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var url = string.Format(Config.GetSearchProductList, text, UserId);
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            productResponce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchProductResponce>(json);
        }

        return productResponce;
    }

    public static async Task<FavouriteProductResponce> AddFavouriteProduct(Dictionary<string, int> data)
    {
        FavouriteProductResponce favouriteProduct;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var jsonData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Config.AddFavourite, jsonData);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            favouriteProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FavouriteProductResponce>(json);
        }
        return favouriteProduct;
    }

    public static async Task<FavouriteProductListResponse> GetFavouriteProducts(int user_id)
    {
        FavouriteProductListResponse favouriteProduct;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var url = string.Format(Config.GetFavouriteProducts, user_id);
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            favouriteProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FavouriteProductListResponse>(json);
        }
        return favouriteProduct;
    }

    public static async Task<DeleteFavouriteProductResponce> DeleteFavouriteProduct(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        DeleteFavouriteProductResponce deleteFavouriteProduct;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
        {
            var jsonData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Config.DeleteFavourite, jsonData);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            deleteFavouriteProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeleteFavouriteProductResponce>(json);
        }
        return deleteFavouriteProduct;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Xamarin code that call the webservice and deserializes the data?  If your json format has not changed it's unlikely an update to Forms would break the code, but without seeing it it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Are your various calls to `DeserializeObject` still working correctly?  This is a multi-step process (request data, php responds to request, deserialize, bind to UI, etc) and you need to start by identifying which step is causing the problem.

Comment: in that piece code, favourite, favoriteProductList abd deleteFavouriteProduct work fine.. if i change api code, then code works fine ( with all the missing fields that i delete from api )..

Comment: You're not answering my question.  For the methods that "don't work" you need to determine where they are breaking down.  You need to step through the code in the debugger and determine **at what specific point** they stop working.